# How to change wsdl binding method?

Tags: c#, wsdl, asmx, rpc

I want to add a **wsdl** API reference in Visual studio 2010. But this reference should be in `RPC` format. The default format is `document`. So how I will change it into RPC while adding reference?

Because if API in document format then I get follwing error,

> Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element
>   (uri:"http://v3.hotel.wsapi.ean.com/", local:"HotelListRequest").
>   Expected elements are <{}HotelListRequest>

If you have any suggestion please tell.

Comment: Why do you believe that the reference is in `document` format?

Comment: Because document is default format.

Comment: Well i get the answer...

1st i create the .cs file from wsdl using wsdl.exe in vs command prompt than replace the SoapDocumentMethodAttribute with SoapRpcMethodAttribute and remove some propperties which are not working with rpc format.And i'm able to get access the API..

Comment: This should not have been a problem. If the WSDL said it was RPC, then RPC should have been generated.